# how to use a time mask for textbox in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to have a time mask for one of my textboxes:

@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.time, ..?)

how can i set a mask like:

18:00 => stored as a string '1800'

Comment: Unless there is something out-of-the box, you might need to write your own html helper. i.e: `Html.MaskedTextBox(model => model...., "##.##")` for example and your helper will format the input data correctly add the required validators, hook up the required scripts to keep the format on change etc.. shouldn't be to dramatic to implement I would think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127093/asp-net-ajax-controls-in-mvc3